# Trying to load default chrome profile using Selenium and Ruby for testing

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium

Currently, I'm using Selenium and Ruby for Cucumber testing. An issue I ran into was that the chrome tab that is made during my testing does not have the settings associated with my normal browsing Chrome tab, which I need because I want to use an extension installed there. Is there a good way to load a default chrome profile with Selenium so that I can achieve this? I haven't had much luck trying the things I found online.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to load the existing chrome profile path using '--user-data-dir'

Example:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
class MyClass
dir='path of your existing chrome profile'
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, :switches => %W[--ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir=#{dir} --enable-logging]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `ChromeOptions` to pass the path to an extension you want to load on starting the browser:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Generally your tests should not rely on the state of your personal browser. One of the perks of using selenium webdrivers is to actually having a defineable fixed state to start with.